# How could I allocate 1D array by using pointer to pointer (int **)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

What is the difference in

```
void AllocateArray(int **arr,int size)
```

and:

```
void AllocateArray(int *arr,int size)
```

I have to allocate only 1D array by using both, and what is difference?

Comment: What do you mean "I have to allocate only 1D array by using both"?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the usage should be:

```
int* arr;
AllocateArray(&arr, 10);
// array has been allocated, use arr[0]...arr[9].
// ...
delete[] arr;  // don't forget this
```

According to the function's name, it might allocate the memory for the array. Such as:

```
void AllocateArray(int **arr,int size) {
    *arr = new int[size];
}
```

The second `AllocateArray`'s parameter(i.e. `int *arr`) is passed by value, that means even the memory is allocated inside the function, it has nothing to do with the outside variable.

Answer (score 1):

> How could i allocate 1D array by using pointer to pointer (int **)

```
int **p=new int*[1];
*p=new int[20];
```

But why? It is too bad to do it like this

> What is the difference

`void AllocateArray(int **arr,int size)` can change the address of the array not just the content of it. In other words:

```
int *p;
AllocateArray(&p,5);
```

Will be able to change where `p` is pointing to.

`void AllocateArray(int *arr,int size)` can only change the content of the array. In other words:

```
int *p;
AllocateArray(p,5);
```

Will be change the content of `p` without changing where it is pointing to.

P.S. I know that `pointer != array` but since it is an elementary question I did not need to dig into such detail for the OP.

**Final Note:**

Please use `std::vector` instead all of these pointers. You will be in peace and feel loved.